# Building Current Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, maven

On the official Selenium blog (http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/) it mentions that Maven is no longer used to build the Selenium project. Can anyone provide me some guidance on the new preferred method for building the selenium project? Everything I've found online is really out of date, referencing the old SVN repos and Maven.

Thanks in advance!

-Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build the new Selenium code we are now using Rake to build everything.

Because Selenium and WebDriver are currently merging a new build process was created. All you need to do is get the latest code out of http://code.google.com/p/selenium and then follow the steps in http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver

There are still a few things that don't build from the Rake file like the .NET stuff but you can build that in Visual Studio.

EDIT:

To build the RC it is `rake selenium-server-standalone`. That will build the jar that you want. It creates the uber jar that has the Selenium 1 RC and the Selenium 2 Remote Driver

Comment: Thanks, but I think I may have been a bit vague in my initial question (oops!). I'm actually looking for how to build the current 1.0 release of Selenium Remote Control, which at the time of this writing is 1.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

A gotcha with using Selenium 2.0a1 and 2.0a2 with Maven: the pom.xml file used to build the Selenium jar containing the WebDriver Selenium emulation (WebDriverBackedSelenium) is not configured to include the required .js files in the Selenium jar. Consequently, both the 2.0a1 and 2.0a2 jars available from the Maven repository are missing these js files, and will not work properly. The same is true for any build using the pom.xml in its current form.
[Bug info here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=412)